# Datastax Opscenter Restore Fails with TLS enabled (node-to-node encryption)?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, opscenter

I am using DSE version 5.09 and Opscenter version 6.08.

Opscenter restore process seems to be failing when node-to-node encryption is enabled on C* nodes. It works successfully when I disable TLS on all nodes and carry out restore process.

Has anyone faced similar issue or Is there a way around to get the restore successfully done without disabling TLS?

Also SSTableloader seems to be failing with node-to-node encryption enabled.

Is DSE restore process using SSTableloader/Opscenter isn't feasible with TLS enabled? Any opinions/comments would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataStax OpsCenter engineer here.

This is a known issue and is tracked internally via the ticket id's DSP-14202 and OPSC-12334, if you have support or access to a sales engineer they can check the status of these tickets for you. I'm not on the DSE team, but my sense is that progress has been made on this issue and that it should be addressed in the next round of patch-releases for DSE.

In the meantime, I think you simply won't be able to use OpsCenter to perform your restores with this configuration. You'd have either disable node-to-node encryption or do restores outside of OpsCenter and pass in extra TLS options like:

- JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dssl.keystore=$2 -Dssl.enabled=true";
- JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dssl.keystore.password=$2";
- JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dssl.truststore=$2 -Dssl.enabled=true";
- JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dssl.truststore.password=$2";

Comment: Thank you for your response.